# Automatically take a Picture

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, iphone-4

I have tried to take a picture and save it to the photo library automatically with UIImagePicker and AVFoundation, but I couldn't make it work.

I would like to take the photo when the view appears, not showing the camera view to the user, and then use it as a simple image in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple actually has an entire guide devoted to this sort of thing, "Camera Programming Topics for iOS," with a subsection "Taking Pictures and Movies." There's even a sample project, "Photo Picker." Here's an excerpt, the action method for your take-a-picture button:

```
- (IBAction)cameraAction:(id)sender {
[self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
```

Note: It won't work unless `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]` returns YES, indicating that the device has a camera.